# Shell commands are written in what language?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kernel

There are many shell commands, like

> ls, cd, cat etc.

what programming language is used in writing these commands? How are they compiled?

My understanding:

```
Shell is a program which takes command; ** does this mean that it interprets those commands(like ls is interpreted by shell program)?**
```

One more question, what language is Shell program written in?

Comment: I am a beginner and getting confused a lot. This may explain me in a much better way.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think they are written in Assembly languages. Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) for more on assembly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the basic utilities in linux are written in `C` .This u can verify in `busybox source code` which supports most of basic linux command utility which are written in `C`.
So command like ls,cd ...etc are in `c`

How shell will interpret check in below link

in an operating system there is a special program called the shell. The shell accepts human readable commands and translates them into something the kernel can read and process.

http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/resources/manuals/Unix_Unleashed/Vol_1/ch08.htm

Comment: Thanks! The article seems very good and easy to understand the kernel and shell working.

Comment: If u want understand how commands works like ls u can check in `busy box source-code`

Comment: I will find out about {busy box source-code }. But if its possible, could you please explain a little.

Answer (score 7):

These programs are mainly written in the C programming language as is the linux kernel.

Comment: As per my understading, commands might be wrtten in Shell programming language, like Bash. While the Shell programs(like Bash) are in C language(not sure if it could be Assembly language).

Answer (score 5):

The programs are ordinary executable written in any language (mostly C).

The shell takes a command entered which is just a string. It then looks for certain sequences of characters which have special meaning to the shell such as environmental variables which are `$` followed by a word or redirects which are `>` followed by a path. After this substitution has been preformed it has a string which is split on spaces to generate a name of an executable and parameters. The shell will then search for the executable in the list of directory's in the environmental variable PATH. The shell then uses system calls to create a process from the executable with the parameters.

For example to execute the command `ls $HOME` the shell would first recognize that `$HOME` is an environmental variable and substitute it for its value in this case `/home/user` leaving the command `ls /home/user`. It then splits the command to on the space to get the executable name `ls` and parameter `/home/user`. The shell finds the first executable that matches `ls` usually `/bin/ls`. It then uses ether the spawn()/ posix_spawn() or fork() and exec() system calls to create the new process.

Comment: Please explain more! by giving an example of a command.
explain below things:
-substituting enviremental variables(which are username etc)
-Generating executables and parameters
-using system calls to create process